# Using Turkish bert model it throws an error that it must be tensor not str

Tags: python, data-science, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to use Turkish bert model with huggingface transformers library. I want to train the model like:

`%%time

history = defaultdict(list)
best_accuracy = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

```
# Show details 
print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}")
print("-" * 10)

train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
    model,
    train_data_loader,
    loss_fn,
    optimizer,
    device,
    scheduler,
    len(df_train)
)

print(f"Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}")

# Get model performance (accuracy and loss)
val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(
    model,
    val_data_loader,
    loss_fn,
    device,
    len(df_val)
)

print(f"Val   loss {val_loss} accuracy {val_acc}")
print()

history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

# If we beat prev performance
if val_acc > best_accuracy:
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')
    best_accuracy = val_acc`
```

it throws an error on first epoch.
The error is : dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str

I tried the solution that return_dict = False but it didn't work

`model_name = 'dbmdz/bert-base-turkish-cased'

## Build a BERT based tokenizer

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name, return_dict=False)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)`

Any idea to solve that problem?